# Linking ThemeDictionaries in Library Project

Tags: xaml, uwp

I created 2 `ResourceDictionary`/theme files in **Themes** folder named `Light.xaml` and `Dark.xaml`.

Added `SolidColorBrush` with name `BgColor` in both files :

`<SolidColorBrush x:Name="BgColor" Color="Silver" />` *// in Light.xaml*

`<SolidColorBrush x:Name="BgColor" Color="WhiteSmoke" />` *// in Dark.xaml*

In `Application` type project, I can add below XAML code in `App.xaml` so I can reference this resource in my `UserControl` :

```
<Application>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark" Source="Themes/Dark.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light" Source="Themes/Light.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Since this is `Library Project`, there's no `App.xaml` on my project.

So how to link this `ThemeDictionaries` so I can use it in my `UserControl` in `Library Project` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how to link this ThemeDictionaries so I can use it in my UserControl?

You can reference the resource dictionary in your `App.xaml` like below:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark" Source="ms-appx:///MyThemeLibrary/Themes/Dark.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light" Source="ms-appx:///MyThemeLibrary/Themes/Light.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

`MyThemeLibrary` is the reference name of your class library. After that you can use the theme that you defined in `Dark.xaml` and `Light.xaml` like below:

```
<UserControl
    ...
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource BgColor}">
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: The `UserControl` itself is in same project / `MyThemeLibrary` not in `Application` type project that has `App.xaml` file. I have edited my question to add this information.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you are using `ThemeDictionary`. I'll update my answer. The solution is the same, just to change `MergedDictionaries` to `ThemeDictionaries`. This solution also works even the user control is in the same class library.

Comment: And here is the [demo](https://github.com/elvisxia/LinkLibrarySample) I made. You can change the `requestedTheme` to see the outcome.

Comment: Thanks, even I feel kinda awkward, but it's works perfect.