# Static resource defined in ThemeDictionaries not fetched while edit a copy of the template for custom control

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

Static resource defined in ThemeDictionaries not fetched while edit a copy of the template for custom control.

Is this is behavior or issue?

In my scenario i want to fetch StaticResource from ThemeDictionaries.

Any workaround is there to achive my requirement?

Note:  I have used ThemeDictionaries to change the color of my control based on Highcontrast, light and default themes

[sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RS6SK2ac-mg_5GA2nmkBuyWIPLyhPNqT/view?usp=sharing)

Regards,
Priyanga B

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this issue is to put the 'ThemeDictionaries' in your main project's `App.xaml` directly. For example:

```xml
<Application
x:Class="CustomControlUWP.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:CustomControlUWP"
xmlns:Input="using:CustomControl1"
RequestedTheme="Light">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Backcolor" Color="Black"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Backcolor" Color="Pink"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrast">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Backcolor" Color="Red"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Another way is to define the ThemeDictionaries in separate xaml files in your class library, and in your main project's `App.xaml`, you could add reference to the resource dictionary like this thread: [Linking ThemeDictionaries in Library Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327157/linking-themedictionaries-in-library-project)

Comment: i am going to provide control as library and allowed to expose the style of the control. In that case static resource from ThemeDictionaries not exposed. Any other workaround is there to expose resource from ThemeDictionaries ?

Comment: I do not think there're other ways. You could check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/themeresource-markup-extension). `As with StaticResource, a ThemeResource must not attempt to make a forward reference to a resource that is defined lexically further within the XAML file. Attempting to do so is not supported. Even if the forward reference doesn't fail, trying to make one carries a performance penalty. For best results, adjust the composition of your resource dictionaries so that forward references are avoided.`